# ZF2 - use url helper to generate non-canonical paths in subdomain

Tags: php, url, zend-framework2, helper, view-helpers

I am using ZF2's URL helper to generate URLs for pages in a subdomain. For example, from within a view:

```
$this->url(
    'photos/album',
    ['albumId' => 1],
    true
);
```

Will generate this URL:

```
http://photos.example.com/album/1
```

However, I would like to generate the non-canonical URL instead:

```
/album/1
```

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried setting the `force_canonical` option to no avail:

```
$this->url(
    'photos/album',
    ['albumId' => 1],
    ['force_canonical' => false],
    true
);
```

My guess is that non-canonical URLs cannot be generated for routes of type `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname`, but I'm not entirely sure.